# Restarting a persisted workflow using a self-hosted WorkflowServiceHost

Tags: wcf, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I'm trying to work out how to resume a persisted workflow that I'm self-hosting with a WorkflowServiceHost. Currently my host wires up persistence and idling behaviour like so:

```
        // Persistence
        var connStr = @"";
        var behavior = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreBehavior(connStr);
        behavior.InstanceCompletionAction = InstanceCompletionAction.DeleteNothing;
        behavior.InstanceLockedExceptionAction = InstanceLockedExceptionAction.AggressiveRetry;
        behavior.InstanceEncodingOption = InstanceEncodingOption.None;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);

        // Idle behaviour
        var idleBehavior = new WorkflowIdleBehavior();
        idleBehavior.TimeToPersist = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
        idleBehavior.TimeToUnload = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
```

I am storing the workflow instance GUID against a ProductID in my database inside a custom activity contained in the workflow, so I am able to easily trace a specific workflow instance to a product ID. I want to be able to somehow pass this Product ID to my ServiceHost and have it resume the correct persisted workflow for me.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Many thanks in advance
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to read about [Content Correlation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358755.aspx).  You'll correlate your ProductID with your Receive activities.  A bookmark will be created when you reach a receive, and your workflow will be persisted.  You call the receive and pass your ProductID in and because of the correlation, the WF runtime knows which instance to resume.

Comment: When you say 'a bookmark will be created when you reach a receive and your workflow will be persisted' - is this implcit behaviour of a receive activity, or do you mean hypothetically there would exist logic in the Receive events to facilitate this process?

Comment: Placing the different receives in pick branches in a pick sequence will allow the workflow to idle when it reaches those receive blocks.  The bookmark is created when it idles and when you call one of the receives, the workflow is resumed.  Try it out, and when it idles, you'll see a row in your InstancesTable (in your SQL db) for your workflow...and under the column "BlockingBookmarks" should be your receive calls.

Comment: Sounds Great Ryan, will give it a go. Do you have any example XAML you could share?

Comment: [MSFT Samples for WF4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en) This should get you started.  You don't set the InstanceStore in XAML, you set it on your workflow host (either the WorkflowApplication or WorkflowServiceHost)